# Why href URLs in IIS show "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" error? (ASP.NET MVC C#)

Tags: c#, iis, deployment, asp.net-mvc-5

I published my ASP.NET MVC Web App to IIS, and it does open my first two pages (Login and Home),
However in my navbar i have multiple menus (links `<a>`) with href.(e.g href="/Users/Index")

When i open my app in browser, 
it shows: http://localhost/AppName/Home

when i click a menu item on my navbar it doesn't add the appname, and doesn't render my view:
http://localhost/User/Index

and sends a HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Obviously if i add the AppName manually it does open the view.

This doesn't happen in VS IDE but when i publish it to IIS, the routing does not seem to work.

Any ideas??

RouteConfig.cs

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Link on Navbar

```
 <a href="/User/Index" class="dropdown-toggle"> Users</a>
```

My web.config does have:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How can we possibly help if you don't show us any code?

Comment: Sorry, i edited my comment now

Comment: Because your application path is different than your root path.
You have 2 ways to solve this: move the application to the root folder or use ~/ instead of /

Comment: also linking should be handled via code with helpers like @Html.Action() or asp attributes

Comment: @VeNoMiS I will have to use @Html.Action() for all my links from now on, funny this didn't happen with older apps i've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update!

Following VeNoMiS's advice, i inserted Url.Action to all my navbar menu items, spliting the URL i got from my database into each parameter (view, controller, area).

All routing from within IIS worked perfectly.

```
<a href="@Url.Action(Url.Split('/')[2], Url.Split('/')[1], new { Area = Url.Split('/')[3] })"><span class="@Icon" title="@Icon"></span> @Name</a>
```

Cheers